# nginx mac invalid pid?

Tags: macos, nginx

I just installed nginx. I am trying to stop it now using the pid file in the logs folder but it's telling me that it's `illegal process id: cat /usr/local/logs/nginx.pid`

The command that i run is: `sudo kill 'cat /usr/local/logs/nginx.pid'`

The pid is `15597` but in Activity Monitor i don't see a process with that ID either. When I type: `ps ax | grep nginx` i get:

```
15597   ??  Ss     0:00.00 nginx: master process nginx
15883   ??  S      0:00.00 nginx: worker process
15898 s000  R+     0:00.00 grep nginx
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to kill the process directly:

`kill 15597`

or you can try the nginx start script in usr/local/etc/nginx:

```
nginx -s quit
```

You will probably have to adjust the path according to your installation.